# sum results in drupal webform grid

Tags: drupal, grid, sum, drupal-webform

I created a webform in drupal, and added a grid component in it.
The grid has 13 questions and 3 options (good, bad, terrible).
its like a poll and people come and answer the questions.
in results, i have sum for each option in each question.
what i need is sum for options in all of questions.
for example i need a sum row in grid footer!

i tried webform submissions in views, but it does not give me the data stored in grid.

needless to say i'm noob in php and i dont know how to make tpl.

image in this link says it all:
[i need sum row in grid footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDskW.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you have created your grid using a custom code, you can add required rows to as you do with normal html. Then you can calculate totals in javascript/jquery and set the totals into above added row columns. To access elements easily you have to maintain html ids and classes accordingly.

However if you can explain the full scenario, it will be easy for us to look at the drupal's point of view.